# Using GeoCharts with GWT application to create map. How do I draw shapes?

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, charts, google-visualization

Currently I have a GWT 2.8 project. In that project I use Geocharts to draw out maps of the USA. The exact package I use is the following.
com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.geochart

I was wondering if anyone had any example code that would allow me to draw shapes similar to how it is done here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple
The basics of the code I have is the following.

```
GeoChart chart = new GeoChart();
DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
GeoChartOptions options = GeoChartOptions.create();

##add some longitude and latitude points to draw out ###

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

A starting point would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the [GeoChart from the google-visualization library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) uses SVG

it is easy to draw and add shapes, once the chart's '`ready'` event fires

however, there is no option for drawing shapes similar to the maps api

meaning, you will not be able to set specific lat / lng coordinates for the shape's placement

here is a working snippet that adds a circle and triangle to the chart...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages: ['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(chartDiv);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var svg = chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    circle.setAttribute('cx', '380');
    circle.setAttribute('cy', '80');
    circle.setAttribute('r', '72');
    circle.setAttribute('stroke', '#000000');
    circle.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
    circle.setAttribute('fill', 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)');
    svg.appendChild(circle);

    var poly = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');
    poly.setAttribute('points', '50,400 210,400 210,50');
    poly.setAttribute('stroke', '#000000');
    poly.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
    poly.setAttribute('fill', 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)');
    svg.appendChild(poly);
  });
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```